# How to Disable Databinding during Insert new Row Button Click

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

As i click on the Insert new Row, the Grid goes into databinding and i just want to disable the databinding to the Edit Template during insert new row, how is it possible ?

Secondly how is it possible that during edit mode it is able to recognize a dataitem to which the textbox is binded to and during add new row command it displays the error  ‘Telerik.WebControls.GridInsertionObject does not contain a property’ ??

I tried

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName)
    {
        e.Canceled = true;
    }
}
```

But this code just cancel the whole insert item template creating process..

Answer (score 0):

itemcommand event will fire only on edit,insert,delete,update command on grid rows.

but if you want to avoid databinding use

```
GRIDVIEW_ITEMDATABOUND() 
{
}
```

try this

Comment: what i want is no databinding to the edit item template section during insert command...I don't know why that data binding happens during insert command even though i have disabled automatic insert..

Comment: are you binding grid when you are inserting rows to grid??

Comment: well telerik grid behaves that way, it binds the grid during insert operation also..and that is the thing which is creating problem for me

Reason: even i don't know why ...